# How do I make the Samba work after editing its configuration?

Tags: ubuntu, network-shares, samba, vmware-workstation

I need some help regarding Samba in Ubuntu (Where Ubuntu is installed in VMWare Workstation 8). I followed a video tutorial. Here are the things I did:

1. First, I installed Samba using this: `sudo apt-get install samba smbfs`
2. `cd /etc/samba`
3. I then proceeded to creating a backup of the smb.conf `cp smb.conf smb.conf.bak`
4. `Vi smb.conf`
5. Uncomment the `security line: security = user`
6. Retain and uncomment the `workgroup = WORKGROUP` as well as the `server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)`.
7. I added `hosts allow = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` (IP of my Linux)
8. I created a user using `smbpasswd -a username` and set a password for it.
9. Using `testparm` and enter, I saw the service definitions like [global], [printers], [smbdemo]
   10.I tried `service smb restart` but it says **No command 'service' found, did you mean: Command 'service' from package 'sysvinit-utils' (main) service: command not found** but when I tried `sudo restart smbd` I got **smbd start/running, process 3602** so I assumed that the Samba already restarted.
10. So I proceeded to my Windows Network and typed the IP of my Ubuntu installed in VMWare and the username with this pattern: **\ip.ip.ip.ip\username** but it cannot be connected.

I want to know if I missed a couple of steps or if I did something wrong. I would also like to know, how do I make sure that the Samba already restarted? Hope you could help me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your Samba daemon seems to be running OK.
Test if it is listening for incoming connections on port 445TCP:

```
$ netstat -ano | grep "445" -i
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN    off (0.00/0/0)
```

Or from another computer:

```
$ nmap YourUbuntuMachine -p 445
Host is up (0.0010s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
```

It yes, Samba should be working, and you may be able to connect to its IP running from Windows:

```
\\YourUbuntuMachine
```

You should see your shared resources... maybe none until you add them at **smb.conf**. For example:

```
[NameDesired]
    comment = Any comments even with spaces and without quotes
    path = /media/sda3
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = no
    read only = no
    create mask = 0755
```

And, by the way, the user connecting should be able to enter your shared device (**/media/sda3** here): try login with his name to make sure.